# How to properly loop through an array to form association map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a small application that given the latitude and longitude of a vessel from [AIS Hub](https://www.aishub.net/api), will locate the boat and show its logo on a `google-map`.
I mapped each compay and each logo. Now after looping through the companies, I would like to associate its logo. I am having issues with associating company with iots logo.
Below asnippet of code that does what I need but loop is not complete:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Table } from 'reactstrap';

const shipCompanyMap = {
    Vessel_A: 'COMPANY-A',
    Vessel_B: 'COMPANY-B',
    Vessel_C: 'COMPANY-C',
    // Other companies...
};

const companyImageMap = {
    COMPANY-A: '../src/logos/company_A.jpg',
    COMPANY-B: '../src/logos/company_B.png',
    COMPANY-C: '../src/logos/company_C.png',
    // Other logos...
};

const Ship = ({ ship }) => {
    const shipName = ship.NAME;
    const company = shipCompanyMap[shipName];
    const shipImage = companyImageMap[company];

    return (
        <div>
            <img src={shipImage} alt="ships" /> // <-- Loop here vessel to match it with its logo
        </div>
    );
};

const ShipTracker = ({ ships }) => {
    return (
        <div className="ship-tracker">
            <Table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Callsign</th>
                        <th>Heading</th>
                        <th>SOG</th>
                        <th>IMO</th>
                        <th>MMSI</th>
                        <th>Longitude</th>
                        <th>Latitudee</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {ships.map((ship, index) => {
                        const { IMO, NAME, CALLSIGN, HEADING, SOG, MMSI, LONGITUDE, LATITUDE } = ship;
                        const cells = [ NAME, CALLSIGN, HEADING, SOG, IMO, MMSI, LONGITUDE, LATITUDE ];
                        return (
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">{index}</th>
                                {cells.map((cell) => <td>{cell}</td>)}
                            </tr>
                        );
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        </div>
    );
};

export default ShipTracker;
```

**What I have done so far:**

1) I believe this is a loop problem. I have tried to loop thougth the company extracted by the API provided and extracted its position, I was trying to match that company with its logo and show it on a `google-map` but I am not sure how to organize the loop.

2) After doing some research I came across the [filtering function](https://alligator.io/js/filter-array-method/) and tried to use a bit but realized that this is not probably what I need as my association shouold be company <--> logo.

3) I am not passing an object. I suspected that I had to treat it as an array and started working in that direction. But since I am not passing a "real" object but am trying to make an association map, working to pass the object was not a good way.

4) I figured out a way to show it by `returning` the ship using the following rendering method but:

```
return (
            <div>
                <img src={shipImage} alt="ships" /> // <-- Loop here vessel to match it with its logo
            </div>
```

But still have not been able to solve the loop to associate company with its own image.
What am I am doing wrong? Am I going in the right direction? 
Thanks for pointing in the right direction for solving this problem.

Comment: First -> `const companyImageMap = {COMPANY-A: '../src/logos/company_A.jpg',..}` is invalid Javascript, and the code you supplied doesn't even using `Ship`.

Comment: @Keith, thank for reading the question. I wrote `Ship` as I thought this could be a good way to use it to structure the serach, but I don't know how to supply it inside the code in order to operate the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`#Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const shipCompanyMap = {
  Vessel_A: 'COMPANY-A',
  Vessel_B: 'COMPANY-B',
  Vessel_C: 'COMPANY-C',
  // Other companies...
};

const companyImageMap = {
  'COMPANY-A': '../src/logos/company_A.jpg',
  'COMPANY-B': '../src/logos/company_B.png',
  'COMPANY-C': '../src/logos/company_C.png',
  // Other logos...
};

const associationMap = Object.values(shipCompanyMap).reduce((acc, curr) => ({
  ...acc,
  [curr]: companyImageMap[curr],
}), {});

console.log(associationMap);
```

Also, [thats not how you import images with webpack](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/).

For example:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.png'; // Tell Webpack this JS file uses this image
console.log(logo); // /logo.84287d09.png

function Header() {
  // Import result is the URL of your image
  return <img src={logo} alt="Logo" />;
}

export default Header;
```

In your case:

```
import glddImage from './logos/gldd.png'

const companyImageMap = {
  GREATLAKESDREDGEANDDOCK: glddImage,
  ...
};
```

Comment: thanks for reading the question. I am still not able to visualize the logo on the map. Is that due to the <div></div> missing loop I was trying to do ? Is `Ship` still going to be used? sorry but I am a bit confused.

Comment: Make a sandbox (codesandbox.io) without it, it only guessing for me

Comment: Thanks, [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/silly-flower-ecbe6?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) is the sandbox.

Comment: Its not working, "Table is not defined", also, thats not how you import images, using such path won't work, I'll add an example

Comment: Sorry I missed one module. I just added the missing `import { Table } from 'reactstrap';` in the sandbox